# Mongoose lookup id of each item?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of Workouts - Each workout holds a reference to a WorkoutCategoryId. But the API shouldn't only return the categoryId, but the whole category ifself. So I somehow need to lookup the WorkoutCategory, from the WorkoutCategoryId, and populate this.

Right now im finding all Workouts related to a client:

```
let workouts = await Workout.find({
       clientId: clientId
});
if(workouts) {
   return workouts
}
```

Great, all this works as it should, but as I wrote, this returns an array of Workout:

```
0: {_
  id: "5efc518032844e24c74371ec", name: "A name2", createdBy: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b1",…}
  clientId: "5ef08f6b25fbdc481b01a82b"
  createdBy: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b1"
  workoutCategoryId: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b9"
  name: "A name2"
},
1: {_
  id: "5efc518032844e24c74371ec", name: "A name2", createdBy: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b1",…}
  clientId: "5ef08f6b25fbdc481b01a82b"
  createdBy: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b1"
  workoutCategoryId: "5ee75b17558756773c2dd4b9"
  name: "A name2"
}
```

So my question is, how to I extend this, so I also get the actual workoutCategory in each item my response?

I've tried .map() on workouts, and tried extending the object, but cant quite get that to work...

```
workouts = workouts.map((workout) => {
                let workoutCategoryId = workout.workoutCategoryId;
                WorkoutCategory.find({_id: workoutCategoryId}).then((category) => {
                    workout.category = category
                });
                return workout;
            })
```

I've seen a few articles on someone suggestion to use $lookup of .aggregate(), but I cant quite wrap my head around it and are a bit stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using populate. Assuming "workoutCategoryId" stores objectId referring to the WorkoutCategory Model.

```
Workout.find({
    clientId: clientId
})
.populate('workoutCategoryId')
.exec(function(err, workout){

})
```

With lookup. Try this.

```
Workout.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {clientId: clientId}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {from: "WorkoutCategory", localField: "workoutCategoryId", foreignField: "_id", as: "workoutCategory"}
    }
], (err, w) => {
    console.log(w)
})
```

In, "w", it will be stored as workoutCategory(array).

Comment: And if you just want to select specific fields from WorkoutCategory model then modify the populate as follow: .populate('workoutCategoryId', 'name category')

Comment: Beautiful - That really helped a lot :)